# How to - UDP NAT traversal using BSD sockets

Tags: router, nat, socket, p2p

I have been reading the NAT traversal requiring the use of an external STUN server. There are few public [STUN servers](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN) but I do not know how to use them to find out my public IP that can be used by the other client to initiate the connection. Being a noob in this, I am not able to find out the correct documents for this using the BSD sockets. If someone can explain how can i find my public IP taking BSD sockets as base would be good. Also if you can provide good links for this, it wpuld also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the STUN bind response. [RFC 5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#page-7), the STUN specification, explains how on page 7:

> The STUN server copies that source transport address into an XOR-MAPPED-
> ADDRESS attribute in the STUN Binding response and sends the Binding
> response back to the STUN client.  As this packet passes back through
> a NAT, the NAT will modify the destination transport address in the
> IP header, but the transport address in the XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS
> attribute within the body of the STUN response will remain untouched.
> In this way, the client can learn its reflexive transport address
> allocated by the outermost NAT with respect to the STUN server.